# New way to programmatically get comments for opengraph actions?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Previously, I could use code like this (with the javascript api):

```
    if (OGActionObject.comments.count > 0) {
        // access comment data inside OGActionObject.comments.data ...

    }
```

But recently, OGActionObject.comments.count is accurate, but there is no longer a property called OGActionObject.comments.data. To put it another way, it previously downloaded the comment data automatically when I would do a get on the action id. but now, it seems not to.

Has anyone else noticed this? Is anyone else successfully getting comments of actions via the graph api? Interestingly, I can still post comments via the graph api.

Thanks...

-Ben

Answer (score 0):

So, after looking further, there are several defects open for this. It seems that the July 2013 changes included several changes to the comments API, and this broke comments. Here's a link to one bug report:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/143202602535897?browse=search_51bf84db03f4f5f92821673

There are several others. I hope this gets fixed...

-Ben